# Vim tcomment plugin changes the hyphens in untagged text (html) to html code (& #45;)

Tags: comments

When editing html in Vim, I'll write the class name of the section that I am working on like this:

```
mid-med
```

It is untagged plain text.

I'll call tcomment to comment that out. What I expect to have happen is this:

```
<!-- mid-med -->
```

Instead I get this:

```
<!-- mid&#45;med -->
```

tcomment is converting the plain-text hyphen into html character code.

Is there anyway to prevent tcomment from doing this?

I searched "help:tcomment" but I couldn't find or make sense of anything.

I could just create the comment code first then type in the text but that's counter-intuitive and messing up my workflow.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you try [the issue tracker](https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim/issues)?

Comment: I can reproduce the problem on a Debian with vim 7.4 (both terminal and gVim). That might not be the best answer possible but you could give a try to [nerdCommenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter) which doesn't have this problem.

Comment: I suppose this is, because nested comments are not allowed in HTML/XML. But best would be to use the issue tracker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to a file `~/.vim/ftplugin/html.vim`:

```
let g:tcomment#replacements_xml = {}
```

Comment: That do solves the problem but could you detail a little more your answer to explain why it works please? :-)

Comment: @statox Not really.  It works because the code uses `g:tcomment#replacements_xml` for translations.  Now, why does the code do that for HTML files, is a good question.  A question you'd have to ask `tcomment`'s author though.  Personally I suspect it's a bug, but the author might disagree. :)

Comment: my pwd was "~/.vim/bundle/html5.vim/ftplugin/html.vim". Solution worked like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just updating the answers to this question, as I encountered this annoyance and I found a solution.

Edit `~/.vim/bundle/tcomment_vim/autoload/tcomment.vim` (line ~152):

```
                "\     '-': '&#45;',
                "\     '&': '&#38;',
                \     '-': '-',
                \     '&': '&',
```

I.e., simply replace `-` with `-` ...

Restart Vim.

Details here: https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim/issues/253

[image]